# Merge apache-commons-beanutils and beanutils

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We have [apache-commons-beanutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-beanutils) (108 questions) and [beanutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanutils) (31 questions) and both relate to the same Apache library. I'd like to retag all [beanutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanutils) to [apache-commons-beanutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-beanutils).

Can a moderator do this quickly or am I best to get my hands dirty?

Comment: May as well just retag the 31...

Comment: @Charles I debated that. I wasn't sure whether that was the correct way to do it, bumping 31 questions to the top of the queue. But I'm happy to do that if it's the right way to tidy this up.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've done the deed manually. [beanutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanutils) is no more.